# Runtime textbox creation creates issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, textbox, runtime

This code works fine for first two times,i.e ,when i click on "Add more solution" it creates a new row and controls respectively but when i click on  "Add more solution" for the third time and "add step" button respective to that,,it creates problem.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        for (int i = 0; i < TotalNumberAdded; i++)
        {
            AddControls((i + 1), plcSolution);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < TotalNumberSolAdded; i++)
        {

            AddMoreControls((i + 1), plcAddMoreSolution, 1);
            Button b = (Button)plcAddMoreSolution.FindControl("btn" + (i+1));

            for (int j = 0; j < TotalNumberSolStepAdded; j++)
            {

                AddMoreStepControls((j + 1), plcAddMoreSolution);
            }
        }


}



protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


        TotalNumberAdded++;
        AddControls(TotalNumberAdded, plcSolution);

}
private void AddControls(int controlNumber, PlaceHolder plc)
{
        TextBox txtBoxSolution = new TextBox();
        Label lblSolution = new Label();

        txtBoxSolution.ID = "txtBoxSolution" + controlNumber;
        txtBoxSolution.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;

        txtBoxSolution.Width = 470;
        txtBoxSolution.Height = 50;
        lblSolution.ID = "lblSolution" + controlNumber;

        lblSolution.Text = "Step " + (controlNumber + 1) + ": ";
        lblSolution.Width = 200;


        plc.Controls.Add(lblSolution);

        plc.Controls.Add(txtBoxSolution);



}

protected int TotalNumberAdded
{

    get { return (int)(ViewState["TotalNumberAdded"] ?? 0); }
    set { ViewState["TotalNumberAdded"] = value; }
}


protected void btnAlternate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblSol.Text = "Solution 1";
    string str = (string)ViewState["btnId"];
    if (str != null)
    {
        btn = (Button)plcAddMoreSolution.FindControl(str);

        btn.Visible = false;

    }

    btnAdd.Visible = false;
    TotalNumberSolAdded++;
    AddMoreControls(TotalNumberSolAdded, plcAddMoreSolution,1);

}
protected int TotalNumberSolAdded
{

    get { return (int)(ViewState["TotalNumberSolAdded"] ?? 0); }
    set { ViewState["TotalNumberSolAdded"] = value; }
}
private void AddMoreControls(int controlNumber, PlaceHolder plc,int n)
{

        TextBox txtBoxMoreSolution = new TextBox();

        Label lblMoreSolution = new Label();
         btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = "add step";
        btn.ID = "btn" + controlNumber;
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        ViewState["btnId"] = btn.ID;
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = "soltuion" + (controlNumber + 1);
        lbl.ID = "moreSolution" + (controlNumber + 1);
        lbl.Font.Size = 20;
        lbl.Font.Underline = true;

        txtBoxMoreSolution.ID = "txtBoxMoreSolution" + controlNumber;
        txtBoxMoreSolution.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;

        txtBoxMoreSolution.Width = 470;
        txtBoxMoreSolution.Height = 50;
        lblMoreSolution.ID = "lblMoreSolution" + controlNumber;

        lblMoreSolution.Text = "Step " + n + ": ";
        lblMoreSolution.Width = 200;



        plc.Controls.Add(lbl);

        plc.Controls.Add(lblMoreSolution);

        plc.Controls.Add(txtBoxMoreSolution);

        plc.Controls.Add(btn);



}

private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TotalNumberSolStepAdded++;
    AddMoreStepControls(TotalNumberSolStepAdded, plcAddMoreSolution);
}

protected int TotalNumberSolStepAdded
{

    get { return (int)(ViewState["TotalNumberSolStepAdded"] ?? 0); }
    set { ViewState["TotalNumberSolStepAdded"] = value; }
}

private void AddMoreStepControls(int controlNumber, PlaceHolder plc)
{

        TextBox txtBoxMoreStepSolution = new TextBox();
        Label lblMoreStepSolution = new Label();

        txtBoxMoreStepSolution.ID = "txtBoxMoreStepSolution" + controlNumber;
        txtBoxMoreStepSolution.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;

        txtBoxMoreStepSolution.Width = 470;
        txtBoxMoreStepSolution.Height = 50;
        lblMoreStepSolution.ID = "lblMoreStepSolution" + controlNumber;

        lblMoreStepSolution.Text = "Step " + (controlNumber +1) + ": ";
        lblMoreStepSolution.Width = 200;


        plc.Controls.Add(lblMoreStepSolution);

        plc.Controls.Add(txtBoxMoreStepSolution);


}
```

Comment: `it creates problem` could you tell what problem it creates **exactly**?

Comment: and what problem it creates, please tell the problem description

Comment: When i click on add more solution and after it when i click on add step,, it removes the step already created in the first two solutions and appends it to solution 3.It looks like solution 3 has all the steps from 1 to n and previously created steps merge into the latest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code will help you.. it works fine...

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    for (int i = 0; i < TotalNumberAdded; i++)
    {
        AddControls(i + 1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < TotalNumberSolAdded; i++)
    {
        AddMoreControls((i + 1), 1);
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["t"];
        if (dt != null)
        {
            if ((TotalNumberSolAdded - dt.Rows.Count == 1) && (counter1 == dt.Rows.Count))
            {
                break;
            }
            if (i != 0)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++)
                {
                    int a1 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[k][0].ToString());
                    b = a1 + b;

                }
                start = b - int.Parse(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                b = int.Parse(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
                start = 0;
            }
            for (int j = start; j < b; j++)
            {
                counter++;
                AddMoreStepControls((j + 1), counter);
            }
            b = 0;
            counter = 0;
            counter1++;
        }
    }

}

 private void AddControls(int controlNumber)
    {
    TextBox txtBoxSolution = new TextBox();
    Label lblSolution = new Label();

    txtBoxSolution.ID = "txtBoxSolution" + controlNumber;
    txtBoxSolution.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;

    txtBoxSolution.Width = 470;
    txtBoxSolution.Height = 50;
    lblSolution.ID = "lblSolution" + controlNumber;

    lblSolution.Text = "Step " + (controlNumber + 1) + ": ";
    lblSolution.Width = 200;


    plcSolution.Controls.Add(lblSolution);

    plcSolution.Controls.Add(txtBoxSolution);

      }
 protected int TotalNumberAdded
    {

        get { return (int)(ViewState["TotalNumberAdded"] ?? 0); }
        set { ViewState["TotalNumberAdded"] = value; }
    }
protected void btnAlternate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Number = 0;
        lblSol.Text = "Solution 1";
        string str = (string)ViewState["btnId"];
        if (str != null)
        {
            btn = (Button)plcAddMoreSolution.FindControl(str);
            btn.Visible = false;
        }
        btnAdd.Visible = false;
        TotalNumberSolAdded++;
        AddMoreControls(TotalNumberSolAdded, 1);
        }
    protected int TotalNumberSolAdded
        {
            get { return (int)(ViewState["TotalNumberSolAdded"] ?? 0); }
            set { ViewState["TotalNumberSolAdded"] = value; }
        }
     private void AddMoreControls(int controlNumber, int n)
        {

        TextBox txtBoxMoreSolution = new TextBox();
        Label lblMoreSolution = new Label();
        btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = "add step";
        btn.ID = "btn" + controlNumber;
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        ViewState["btnId"] = btn.ID;
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = "Soltuion" + (controlNumber + 1);
        lbl.ID = "moreSolution" + (controlNumber + 1);
        lbl.Font.Size = 20;
        lbl.Font.Underline = true;
        lbl.Font.Bold = true;
        txtBoxMoreSolution.ID = "txtBoxMoreSolution" + controlNumber;
        txtBoxMoreSolution.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;

        txtBoxMoreSolution.Width = 470;
        txtBoxMoreSolution.Height = 50;
        lblMoreSolution.ID = "lblMoreSolution" + controlNumber;

        lblMoreSolution.Text = "Step " + n + ": ";
        lblMoreSolution.Width = 200;


        plcAddMoreSolution.Controls.Add(lbl);

        plcAddMoreSolution.Controls.Add(lblMoreSolution);

        plcAddMoreSolution.Controls.Add(txtBoxMoreSolution);

        plcAddMoreSolution.Controls.Add(btn);


        }
    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TotalNumberSolStepAdded++;
            Number++;
            string str = (string)ViewState["btnId"];
            if (str != null)
        {
            string resultString = Regex.Match(str, @"\d+").Value;
            a = int.Parse(resultString);
            table = (DataTable)ViewState["t"];
            if (table == null)
            {
                DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
                table1.Columns.Add("count", typeof(int));
                dr = table1.NewRow();
                table1.Rows.Add(dr);
                table1.Rows[a - 1]["count"] = Number;
                table1.AcceptChanges();
                ViewState["t"] = table1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (a != table.Rows.Count)
                {
                    dr = table.NewRow();
                    table.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
                table.Rows[a - 1]["count"] = Number;
                table.AcceptChanges();
                ViewState["t"] = table;
            }
        }


        AddMoreStepControls(TotalNumberSolStepAdded, Number);
    }
 protected int TotalNumberSolStepAdded
    {
        get { return (int)(ViewState["TotalNumberSolStepAdded"] ?? 0); }
        set { ViewState["TotalNumberSolStepAdded"] = value; }
    }

    protected int Number
    {
        get { return (int)(ViewState["Number"] ?? 0); }
        set { ViewState["Number"] = value; }
    }

    private void AddMoreStepControls(int controlNumber, int counter)
    {

        TextBox txtBoxMoreStepSolution = new TextBox();
        Label lblMoreStepSolution = new Label();

        txtBoxMoreStepSolution.ID = "txtBoxMoreStepSolution" + controlNumber;
        txtBoxMoreStepSolution.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;

        txtBoxMoreStepSolution.Width = 470;
        txtBoxMoreStepSolution.Height = 50;
        lblMoreStepSolution.ID = "lblMoreStepSolution" + controlNumber;

        lblMoreStepSolution.Text = "Step " + (counter + 1) + ": ";
        lblMoreStepSolution.Width = 200;


        plcAddMoreSolution.Controls.Add(lblMoreStepSolution);

        plcAddMoreSolution.Controls.Add(txtBoxMoreStepSolution);




    }
```